# networking icon disappearing after restart, on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, graphics

sometimes after I restart my computer the networking icon disappears, I know there must be a command to connect to a desired Wifi but i don't know which one, so my question is: is there a way to fix this ? what is the command to connect to a wifi ?
Greetings

Comment: I use `synapse` which allows me to open the Networking options by typing in Networking.  I haven't figure out a way to resolve this issue and use this workaround until I find a better solution.